# How to create a form where user gives details and also can check what he has entered on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to create a form on wordpress where the user will give the response and then the response is stored as csv , my problem is that i am using weforms and user are able to fill the form and response is stored also but i am not able to display the entries made by that user to himself so that he can change or view his entries later on also . I have made a website using buddy press where i need to take some data in the form so that the data is stored and the user can also check what he has entered and other members can also view his entries by going on his profile

Comment: Use Advanced Custom Fields

Comment: I am new to that ...can you tell me how to dot that